# Replacing the single quotes for columns in select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace

I have 2 tables. In `table1` I have some rows for persons like this:

1. PersonX - ID
2. PersonX - Name
3. PersonX - Address
4. PersonY - ID
5. PersonY - AGE

In 2nd table, above mentioned `ID, NAME,ADDRESS,AGE` will be columns. And we have detailed data of personX and PersonY here.

Now, main issue is in stored procedure, using cursor, I am storing `table1` values (`'ID', 'Name', ...`) in a variable `@Element`.

Now I am using select statement in same cursor as below:

```
SELECT @Element From Table2
```

I need output of user details like his id, age, address etc. But instead I am getting output as `'ID', 'NAME', 'AGE'` etc....

I found that this is because `@Element` is `varchar` and has string value, so select statement is executed as below:

```
SELECT 'ID' from table2.
```

but all I need is like below

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE2
```

I used replace function its not working for me. Case function, I can't use it because we can't say what data is there for a person in `table1`. It varies. I need one dynamic statement which can be use for all records. instead of executing case for each record.

```
SELECT REPLACE(@Element,'''','') 
FROM TABLE2
```

(Still getting 'ID' as output, instead of corresponding value in Table2)

Please help me in this. Hope you understand my explanation

Comment: If you want to **parametrize** table or column names in a `SELECT`, you have to use **dynamic SQL** - create your SQL statement as a `NVARCHAR(x)` variable, and then execute that SQL statement you've built up. There is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this, for example:

```
    CREATE TABLE Table1
(
     ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(255)
    ,ADDRESS VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT Table1 VALUES ('1','Joe Bloggs','Address 1')
INSERT Table1 VALUES ('2','Jane Doe','Address 2')

DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(255) = 'ID'

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT '+@ColName+','+''''+@ColName+''' FROM TABLE1'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

In the first column that is returned, is the SQL you want to be able to execute, however in the 2nd column in my query, is what you're doing at the moment. As far as SQL is concerned, your variable is simply storing a value. It does not know you are referring to a column name which is why it simply returns the value.

Comment: Thanks, May be i can use this. But I would like to know that other than using dynamic SQL, is there any other option. Because prevously we revamped and replaced all the Dynamic SQL.

Comment: In your explanation above. The solution is to use dynamic SQL. However, if you can give us the bigger picture of what you're doing and an example of the cursor, we may be able to find an alternative solution.